# How to Create Set Up File From WPF Application

Tags: wpf, sqlite

[image]

I am trying to create a **set up** file from my **WPF** Application using **InstallShield Limited Edition Project** From **Setup and Deployment** Template in **VS2012.**

And my project contains
1) **multiple Class libraries**.
2) **and Sqlite file for storing data**

I am able to create setup file with out sqlite file but I am unable to create Setup file with Sqlite File.
My question is How to Generate/create SetUp file for Wpf Application Which is using **Sqlite** File.

I have tried my best but not found solution.
Please give me your valuable suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Sqlite file to your project and marked it as 'Content' setting 'Copy to output directory' to something different than 'Do not copy'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I have tried the way you proposed but not working any other suggestions please @AlexSelezny ov

Comment: Can't say exactly without seeing your setup project. Have you checked ISLE documentation, for example, starting from http://helpnet.installshield.com/isxhelp20/Content/helplibrary/IHelpISXFiles.htm#ref-views_3353461163_1084660 ? 

From my previous expirience I remember adding a folder to install project using drag-n-drop worked flawlessly.

Can you add some screenshots with your project structure?

Comment: Please check my project screen shot. I am adding above mentioned files and my sqlite file name is **Grocery.Sqlite** .And one more thing is in my code I have written logic like if sqlite file is not present it will create sqlite file with mentioned name and that is happening but I am unable to create tables with in that sqlite file. In my solution its working fine but with exe file It is not happening can you suggest why its happening.

Comment: Or else please provide your own steps for creating Exe file which includes **Sqlite** file.

Comment: What files are in the install folder after installation is complete? Do you have sqlite's dlls there? Do you get any exception starting installed application?
And btw, it's not a good idea to keep database file in program files - Application Data folder is a way better place.

Comment: I already tried to keep **sqlite**  file in Application Data Folder but its not getting. and in my installation folders I dont get any **Sqlite** Files.  One more doubt is when I am running application in **VS** I am creating some files like saving user details and as well as sqlite file and those files are storing in **bin** folder.But when I created **EXE** why those files are creating out side application. I hope you got my problem. Please let me know why its happening like that.

Comment: What about your connection string? Make sure it is properly built and points to proper folder and file.